# Mayavi/mlab: Plot triangles with colour data per triangle, not per vertex

Tags: python, mayavi

If one uses the function

```
triangular_mesh
```

one can pass a set of triangles, given as lists of indices, the vertex positions and a set of data to to assign colours to the vertices. The triangles are then coloured by interpolation between the vertex colours.

How can I assign colours triangle-wise, without any interpolation?

Answer (score 4):

This was asked on the scipy mailing list too.

You can't do it with triangular_mesh, but you can if you make a generic surface using a triangular mesh as a source.

```
s = mlab.pipeline.triangular_mesh_source(x,y,z,triangles)
s.data.cell_data.scalars = .... # Your data here.
surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(s)
surf.contours.filled_contours = True
```

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-September/053040.html

Comment: In case you want to define a specific color for each triangle via scalar value by creating a lookup-table (lut), you will also need to set `surf.module_manager.lut_data_mode = 'cell data'`.