# Colorize Function for descriptor on 3d Mesh

Tags: python, graph, 3d, feature-extraction

The process is like that:

I represent 3d mesh as graph data structure (adjacency matrix), and I extracted some features from it, now I would like to visualize these features on the mesh (coloring the vertices that it is related for)

I have the access to the XYZ-coordinates,

The graph is this for example:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]]
```

and the extracted features are like:

```
[0.31830989 0.13789404 0.18738977 0.21210616 0.09979722 0.25386089
0.16402911 0.29690689 0.26002601 0.12894862 0.07586501 0.48601007
0.45855364 0.20280874 0.0126834  0.54532024 0.46835978 0.34243193
0.13314587 0.09234412 0.03764165 0.159134   0.45475221 0.1222509
0.17898168]
```

or like

```
 [[ 2.72000000e+03+0.00000000e+00j -3.61459783e+00-2.59278293e+00j
  -2.07518936e+00+5.47244984e+01j ...  4.54069829e+00-1.92151511e+01j
  -2.07518936e+00-5.47244984e+01j -3.61459783e+00+2.59278293e+00j]
 [-3.61459783e+00-2.59278293e+00j  1.58768982e+01+9.65807617e+01j
   5.20680975e+01+3.99595074e+01j ... -4.99445026e+01+7.24088068e+00j
   9.35655863e+01-1.21058601e+02j  2.50985585e+03-2.57571742e-14j]
 [-2.07518936e+00+5.47244984e+01j  5.20680975e+01+3.99595074e+01j
   6.55872731e+01+3.73890215e+01j ...  2.02088720e+02-2.45776099e+02j
   2.02739503e+03-2.13162821e-14j  9.35655863e+01+1.21058601e+02j]
 ...
 [ 4.54069829e+00-1.92151511e+01j -4.99445026e+01+7.24088068e+00j
   2.02088720e+02-2.45776099e+02j ...  8.57571900e+01-4.22466723e+02j
  -1.06818420e+02-3.69249733e+01j  4.09731773e+01-3.35297094e+01j]
 [-2.07518936e+00-5.47244984e+01j  9.35655863e+01-1.21058601e+02j
   2.02739503e+03-3.28626015e-14j ... -1.06818420e+02-3.69249733e+01j
   6.55872731e+01-3.73890215e+01j  5.20680975e+01-3.99595074e+01j]
 [-3.61459783e+00+2.59278293e+00j  2.50985585e+03-3.95239397e-14j
   9.35655863e+01+1.21058601e+02j ...  4.09731773e+01-3.35297094e+01j
   5.20680975e+01-3.99595074e+01j  1.58768982e+01-9.65807617e+01j]]
```

So the question again: **How can I visualize these features on the mesh that in the basic it's a coordinates, edges, faces.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461819/7919597

Comment: Take a look at Mayavi's [`triangular_mesh()'](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.triangular_mesh)

Comment: You should be able to colorize edges and faces as you like. If that does not work, you can also create a custom rendering pipeline.

Comment: as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928866/mayavi-mlab-plot-triangles-with-colour-data-per-triangle-not-per-vertex

Comment: and https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/data.html

Comment: @Joe kindly I may didn't get you idea correctly, the extracted features, how could be visualize,I mean how should they be as an input in my case, suppose we have this mesh [the mesh](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~omeruvia/philosophy/WireframeBunny.html) I would like to show features on it like [the featured mesh](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/48609/versions/7/screenshot.jpg) Just as example, hopefully I was able to make my idea clearer?

Comment: You pass the mesh to the plotting function, the 3d coordinates. And you can pass the features as "scalars", how they are called in Mayavi, to be used for colorizing. Not sure what `triangular_mesh` colorizes as default, the points or the faces. Both work, but one needs a custom pipeline, see above.

Comment: I'm trying to do it like you mentioned, but I got this error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roaa/PycharmProjects/PhDCoding/MainCall.py", line 41, in <module>
    triangular_mesh(X,Y,Z,faces, scalars =np.fft.fft2(g.adjacency_matrix()) )
  File "/home/roaa/anaconda3/envs/PhDCoding/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/helper_functions.py", line 37, in the_function
    return pipeline(*args, **kwargs)
     assert x.shape == scalars.shape
AssertionError ```
scalars are one of the above mentioned.
@Joe

Comment: look at the `.shape` attribute of the numpy arrays you are trying to plot. There is some mismatch, e.g. values without coordinates or the other way round.

Comment: the `.shape` is for example ```(25,)
(480, 480)```
respectively for the previous arrays @Joe

Comment: Try to run and adjust the examples you can find in the Mayavi docs or in the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with the answer of Marco Musy, using his library `vedo`

There are basically infinite ways of visualizing properties of a mesh based on color (which is obviously only 1-dimensional) or additional objects like arrows to represent vectors, or even other simple objects (in this case they are called Glyphs).

The main point (i might be wrong on this or misunderstand you!) is that you only have this information for a subset of points of your mesh and you want to extrapolate this information to the remaining points. This issue is addressed in my answer here:

https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/issues/83#issuecomment-574625775

Other examples that you may find useful for visualization are maybe these:

https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter-examples/blob/master/vtkplotter_examples/basic/glyphs.py

https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter-examples/blob/master/vtkplotter_examples/basic/glyphs_arrows.py

https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter-examples/blob/master/vtkplotter_examples/advanced/meshquality.py

To interpolate vectors:

https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter-examples/blob/master/vtkplotter_examples/advanced/interpolateField.py